# Differentiability for value of p

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have to solve the following problem.

$$f(x) = e^{\frac{1}{|x|}}$$
Where $x\ne0$, and $f(0)=p$
In question a, I've shown for which values of p this function is continuous, and in question b, I need to show for which values of $p$ this function is differentiable. The problem is that I'm not entirely certain what that means. I thought it meant the following limit has to exist:
$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

but I'm not even sure if that's what is being asked, and I'm kind of stuck at that point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
  e^{1/x}& \text{ if }x>0 \\
 e^{-1/x}& \text{ if }x<0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

derivative is

$f'(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 -\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}& \text{ if }x>0 \\
 \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2}& \text{ if }x<0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \,\left( -\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}\right)=-\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^-} \,\left( \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^2}\right)=\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)\ne \lim_{x\to 0^-} f'(x)$$

As the right and left limits are different the function is not differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: Hello, thanks for you response. Since it's the absolute value of x in the power, though, wouldn't that mean f(x) = e^(1/x), also for x<0? In other words, does that mean the function is differentiable for p = -infinity?

Comment: No. $e^{1/|x|}=e^{-1/x}$ for negative $x$. Furthermore $p=-\infty$ makes no sense

Comment: Right, the thing about e^(1/x) was stupid of me to say, coming to think of it. Still, though, that would mean that no value of p exists, such that f(x) is differentiable... Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes. $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$